# Custom fading in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a complex TikZ picture that has a width of say 10cm. I want to use the same picture at another place but want to show only the left 5cm of the picture. To have a "smoother" look, I would like to have a fading effect for the following 1cm, i.e., I want to see 0cm - 5cm normally, a linear "fade-out" of 5cm to 6cm, and nothing (= transparent or clipped) at 6cm - 10cm. Is this possible in TikZ? The standard `path fading` and `scope fading` don't seem to support such a customization.

Comment: Please provide minimal (non)working example, what you try to do so far.

Comment: There should be no difference between a fading image and a fading (in the opposite direction) white overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I placed a 10cm wide image into a savebox.  One could do the same for  the original tikzpicture.  Then I created two 6cm wide copies with fading edges.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}}%
%
\begin{minipage}{6cm}% only needed for standalone class
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (6cm,\ht\mybox);
\node[above right,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\usebox{\mybox}};
\fill[white,path fading=west]
  (5cm,0) rectangle (6cm,\ht\mybox);
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (6cm,\ht\mybox);
\node[above left,inner sep=0pt] at (6cm,0) {\usebox{\mybox}};
\fill[white,path fading=east]
  (0,0) rectangle (1cm,\ht\mybox);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only if the background is white?

Comment: @cfr - Yes, the color has to match the background.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking much too complicated.